# A keyword to reference the current object as a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I have a simple generic delegate:

```
delegate void CommandFinishedCallback<TCommand>(TCommand command) 
    where TCommand : CommandBase;
```

I use it in the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class CommandBase
{
    public CommandBase()
    { }

    public void ExecuteAsync<TCommand>(CommandFinishedCallback<TCommand> callback)
        where TCommand : CommandBase
    {
        // Async stuff happens here

        callback.Invoke(this as TCommand);
    }
}
```

While this does work, I have no way of forcing the TCommand passed into Execute to be the type of the current object (the more derived CommandBase).

I've seen this solved by doing:

```
public abstract class CommandBase<TCommand>
    where TCommand : CommandBase<TCommand>
{ 
    // class goes here
}
```

But I'm wondering why there isn't a C# keyword for accomplishing that? What I'd love to see is something like the following:

```
public void ExecuteAsync<TCommand>(CommandFinishedCallback<TCommand> callback)
    where TCommand : This
{
    // Async stuff happens here

    callback.Invoke(this);
}
```

Note the capital T on "This". I'm by no means a language designer, but I'm curious if I'm out to lunch or not. Would this be something the CLR could handle?

Maybe there's already a pattern for solving the problem?

Comment: I've added a proposal request to the Roslyn team on GitHub for very nearly this exact feature.  Check it out here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no `thistype` constraint. There are some musings on this topic by Eric Lippert here: [Curiouser and curiouser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx).

Note, in particular, the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (your "solution" to the problem) isn't actually a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing like that in C#.  You're going to have to go with your self-referencing generic class definition if you want to do this at all.